# Javascript - Get info for multiple images from their URL, then insert them into DOM

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I need to get the height and width of an image from it's url and display that image differently based on the orientation of the image (portrait or landscape). I get the image through an API request.

I'm currently using the following code, and the code I need help with begins with the line `var img = new Image;` inside the `attachments if statement` in the `case: 'link'` section of the `switch` statement.

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
  batch: [
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'user',
      relative_url : '/me'
    },
    { 
      method: 'GET', 
      name : 'post-ids',
      relative_url: '/group-id/feed?fields=id',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    { 
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-data',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}&fields=id,actions,application,from,to,message,message_tags,with_tags,picture,place,properties,source,status_type,link,description,caption,attachments,object_id,type,created_time,updated_time,likes.summary(1),comments.summary(1)',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-likes',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}/likes?limit=5000',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-comments',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}/comments?fields=id,actions,application,from,to,message,message_tags,with_tags,picture,place,properties,source,status_type,link,description,caption,attachments,object_id,type,created_time,updated_time,likes.summary(1)&limit=5000',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    }
  ]
}, function (response) {

  var membody = JSON.parse(response[0].body);
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + membody.name);

  var posts = JSON.parse(response[1].body);
  //console.log(posts);
  //console.log(posts.data[0].id);
  var feed = JSON.parse(response[2].body);

  for(var x = 0; x < posts.data.length; x++) {
    //console.log(posts.data[x].id);
    var post = feed[posts.data[x].id];
    console.log(post);

    var entry = '<div class="post">';

    var from_id = post.from.id, 
        from_name = post.from.name,
        post_id = post.id,
        type = post.type,
        created_time = post.created_time; 

    entry += '<div class="post-title"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + from_id + '">' + from_name + '</a> posted a ' + type + ' - <time>' + relativeTime(created_time);

    if(post.application) {
      var app_id = post.application.id,
          app_name = post.application.name,
          app_namespace = post.application.namespace;
      entry += ' via ' + app_name + '</time></div>';
    } else { entry += '</time></div>'; }


    switch(post.type) {

      case 'status' :

        if(post.actions) {
        }

        if(post.message) {
          var message = nl2br(post.message);

          if(post.message_tags) {
            var message_tags = post.message_tags;

            for (var tag in message_tags) {

              if (message_tags.hasOwnProperty(tag)) {
                var message_tag_id = message_tags[tag][0].id;
                    message_tag_length = message_tags[tag][0].length;
                    message_tag_name = message_tags[tag][0].name;
                    message_tag_offset = message_tags[tag][0].offset;
                    message_tag_type = message_tags[tag][0].type;

                var link = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + message_tag_id + '">' + message_tag_name + '</a>';
                message = message.replace(message_tag_name, link);
              }

            } 

          } 

          entry += '<div class="post-message" style="margin:8px 0;">' + message + '</div>';
        }

        if(post.attachments) {
          var att = post.attachments.data[0];
          if(att.description) var att_description = att.description;
          if(att.type) var att_type = att.type;
          if(att.title) var att_title = att.title;
          switch(att.type) {
            case 'unavailable' :
              entry += '<div class="status-att" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 8px;"><div class="status-att-title" style="font-weight: bold;">' + att_title + '</div><div class="status-att-desc">' + att_description + '</div></div>';
            break;
          }
        }                 

        if(post.to) {
          var to_id = post.to.data[0].id,
              to_name = post.to.data[0].name;
        }

        if(post.updated_time) var updated_time = post.updated_time;

        if(post.likes) {
        }

        if(post.comments) {
        }

      break;

      case 'link' :

        console.log(JSON.stringify(post));



        if(post.attachments) {
          var att = post.attachments.data[0];
          if(att.type) var att_type = att.type + 'd';
          else var att_type = 'posted';
        }

        entry += '<div class="post-title"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + from_id + '">' + from_name + '</a> ' + ((att.type) ? 'shared' : 'posted') + ' a ' + type + ' - <time>' + relativeTime(created_time);

        if(post.application) {
          var app_id = post.application.id,
              app_name = post.application.name,
              app_namespace = post.application.namespace;
          entry += ' via ' + app_name + '</time></div>';
        } else { entry += '</time></div>'; }

        if(post.message) {
          var message = nl2br(post.message);

          if(post.message_tags) {
            var message_tags = post.message_tags;

            for (var tag in message_tags) {

              if (message_tags.hasOwnProperty(tag)) {
                var message_tag_id = message_tags[tag][0].id;
                    message_tag_name = message_tags[tag][0].name;

                var link = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + message_tag_id + '">' + message_tag_name + '</a>';
                message = message.replace(message_tag_name, link);
              }

            } 

          } 

          entry += '<div class="post-message" style="margin:8px 0;">' + message + '</div>';
        }

        if(post.attachments) {
          var att = post.attachments.data[0];
          if(att.subattachments) {
            $(att.subattachments.data).each(function (i, item) {
              var sub_img_height = item.media.image.height,
                  sub_img_width = item.media.image.width,
                  sub_img_src = item.media.image.src,
                  sub_target = item.target.url,
                  sub_type = item.type;

              entry += '<img src="' + sub_img_src + '"/><br/>---<br/>' + target + '<br/>---<br/>' + title + '<br/>---<br/>';

            });
          } else {
            var target = att.target.url,
                title = att.title;
            entry += '<a class="link" href="' + (post.link ? post.link : target) + '" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">';
            if(post.picture) {
              // there's a photo
              if(post.picture.indexOf('imdb') > -1) {
                entry += '<div style="float: left; width: 158px;"><img src="' +  post.picture + '" style="width: 158px;"/></div>';

                entry += '<div style="float: left; width: 400px; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="link-title" style="padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold;">' + title + '</div>';
                if (post.description) entry += '<div class="link-desc" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + post.description +  '</div>';
                if (post.caption) entry += '<div class="link-caption" style="font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #888;">' + post.caption + '</div></div></a>';
                entry += '<div class="clear"></div>';
              } else {
                  var picture = post.picture.split('url=');
                  var img = new Image();
                  img.onload = function(){
                    var height = img.height,
                        width = img.width;

                    console.log(decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(picture[1])));
                    console.log('Width: ' + width);
                    console.log('Height: ' + height);

                    if(width > height) {
                      // wide photo, above details
                      entry += '<img src="' + decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(picture[1])) + '" style="max-width:576px; margin-bottom: 0;" />';

                      entry += '<div class="link-details" style="padding: 0 8px 8px 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="link-title" style="padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold;">' + title + '</div>';
                      if (post.description) entry += '<div class="link-desc" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + post.description +  '</div>';
                      if (post.caption) entry += '<div class="link-caption" style="font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #888;">' + post.caption + '</div></div></a>';
                      entry += '<div class="clear"></div>';
                    } else {
                      // tall photo, left of details
                      entry += '<div style="float: left; width: 158px;"><img src="' +  decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(picture[1])) + '" style="max-width: 158px;"/></div>';

                      entry += '<div style="float: left; width: 400px; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="link-title" style="padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold;">' + title + '</div>';
                      if (post.description) entry += '<div class="link-desc" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + post.description +  '</div>';
                      if (post.caption) entry += '<div class="link-caption" style="font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #888;">' + post.caption + '</div></div></a>';
                      entry += '<div class="clear"></div>';
                    }
                  }

                  img.src = decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(picture[1]));
              }

            } else {
              // no picture
              entry += '<div class="link-details" style="width: 558px; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="link-title" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + title + '</div>';
              if (post.description) entry += '<div class="link-desc" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + post.description +  '</div>';
              if (post.caption) entry += '<div class="link-caption" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + post.caption + '</div></div></a>';
            }
          }
        } 

      break;
      case 'photo' :
        if(post.message) {
          var message = nl2br(post.message);

          if(post.message_tags) {
            var message_tags = post.message_tags;

            for (var tag in message_tags) {

              if (message_tags.hasOwnProperty(tag)) {
                var message_tag_id = message_tags[tag][0].id;
                    message_tag_name = message_tags[tag][0].name;

                var link = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + message_tag_id + '">' + message_tag_name + '</a>';
                message = message.replace(message_tag_name, link);
              }

            } 

          } 

          entry += '<div class="post-message" style="margin:8px 0;">' + message + '</div>';
        }

        if(post.attachments) {

          var att = post.attachments.data[0];

          if(att.subattachments) {
            var sub = att.subattachments;

          } else {

            switch(att.type) {
              case 'photo' :
                entry += '<a href="' + att.target.url + '" target="_blank"><img class="post-photo" style="max-height: 576px; max-width: 576px; margin: 8px 0;" src="' + att.media.image.src + '"/></a>';

              break;
              case 'unavailable' : 
                var att = post.attachments.data[0];
                entry += '<div class="status-att" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 8px;"><div class="status-att-title" style="font-weight: bold;">' + att.title + '</div><div class="status-att-desc">' + att.description + '</div></div>';
              break;
            }

          }

        }

      break;
      case 'video' :
      break;
    }

    $('#feed').append(entry);

  }

});
```

There may be one image or many, but each one is part of a larger object in the API results so these images are not handled together.

The problem I'm having is that the images are not displaying at all, and when I log them to the console, only the information for one image is logged: If there are 4 images total, for example, the first image is logged 4 times.

How can I work all this out? I need to be able to display differently oriented images in different ways!

Comment: Please show a larger context of your code around what you've shown so far.  For example is the `img` variable in a function or are you reusing it?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `img.onload` method is async, but I can't tell for sure without more info. If it is async, then you cannot set the img src as you have above

Comment: @jfriend00 this is inside of a very large jQuery.each function, so it's all used multiple times, but only once for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @jasonscript I think I read somewhere that it is asynchronous. I'm guessing that may be the problem? I'll read up on that, but in the meantime, how can I do this synchronously if that's what I need to do?

Comment: synchronous `get`s are possible, but it really isn't recommended because it will block the UI thread for the duration. This results in a slower load experience because nothing else can evaluate while the synchronous `get` is being executed. Strongly recommend not following this approach

Answer (score 1):

Because image loading is asynchronous, you simply can't write the code the way you've done it where you're trying to build up the `entry` variable from various `onload` handlers.  The asynchronous timing of the `onload()` handlers will mess up your coding logic for using the `entry` variable and potentially mess up the ordering of the operations too.

To handle asynchronous operations like this, you have to restructure the way you collect the information and when you process it.  There is no getting around this in JavaScript.  You will need to learn how to do this.

If you show the larger context of what you're trying to do with the `entry` string, then we could help you restructure the overall logic to work in an asynchronous way.  We can't do that with just the code you've shown here because it has to involve a larger picture of what you're doing.

---

Without an ability to test such complicated code, I can't guarantee this is error-free, but hopefully you can see the concept here.

Summary of changes:

1. Keep a counter called `imgCntr` which tells us how many images are currently in flight so we know when the last one is done.
2. Initialize `imgCntr = 1` as a guard so it never gets to zero until all images have been requested.  It is decremented at the end to undo the guard count.
3. Because you are trying to build the `entry` string synchronously, but the image data is not available synchronously, but it needs to go in the right place in that string, we insert a unique placeholder into the string that looks like this `"<<img1>>"`.  Later, when the image data is actually available, we can then replace that unique marker with the desired HTML.
4. In order to protect the variables used in creating temporary images so they aren't overridden by other images, we put them into their own closure.
5. Any outer variables such as `post.description` that you need access to inside the async onload handler must also be passed into the closure so they are preserved uniquely for each image.
6. Rather than do the `$('#feed').append(entry);` only at the end of the function, we also check at the end of each img.onload handler to see if the imgCnt is now down to zero meaning all image data has been retrieved and processed.  At the end of the function, we do not insert the `entry` data unless there are no images outstanding.

Here's the code with those changes (untested since I have no way to actually run it):

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
  batch: [
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'user',
      relative_url : '/me'
    },
    { 
      method: 'GET', 
      name : 'post-ids',
      relative_url: '/group-id/feed?fields=id',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    { 
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-data',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}&fields=id,actions,application,from,to,message,message_tags,with_tags,picture,place,properties,source,status_type,link,description,caption,attachments,object_id,type,created_time,updated_time,likes.summary(1),comments.summary(1)',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-likes',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}/likes?limit=5000',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-comments',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}/comments?fields=id,actions,application,from,to,message,message_tags,with_tags,picture,place,properties,source,status_type,link,description,caption,attachments,object_id,type,created_time,updated_time,likes.summary(1)&limit=5000',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    }
  ]
}, function (response) {

  // imgCntr is set to 1 as a guard so it won't get to zero until all images are done
  var imgCntr = 1;
  var membody = JSON.parse(response[0].body);
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + membody.name);

  var posts = JSON.parse(response[1].body);
  //console.log(posts);
  //console.log(posts.data[0].id);
  var feed = JSON.parse(response[2].body);

  for(var x = 0; x < posts.data.length; x++) {
    //console.log(posts.data[x].id);
    var post = feed[posts.data[x].id];
    console.log(post);

    var entry = '<div class="post">';

    var from_id = post.from.id, 
        from_name = post.from.name,
        post_id = post.id,
        type = post.type,
        created_time = post.created_time; 

    entry += '<div class="post-title"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + from_id + '">' + from_name + '</a> posted a ' + type + ' - <time>' + relativeTime(created_time);

    if(post.application) {
      var app_id = post.application.id,
          app_name = post.application.name,
          app_namespace = post.application.namespace;
      entry += ' via ' + app_name + '</time></div>';
    } else { entry += '</time></div>'; }


    switch(post.type) {

      case 'status' :

        if(post.actions) {
        }

        if(post.message) {
          var message = nl2br(post.message);

          if(post.message_tags) {
            var message_tags = post.message_tags;

            for (var tag in message_tags) {

              if (message_tags.hasOwnProperty(tag)) {
                var message_tag_id = message_tags[tag][0].id;
                    message_tag_length = message_tags[tag][0].length;
                    message_tag_name = message_tags[tag][0].name;
                    message_tag_offset = message_tags[tag][0].offset;
                    message_tag_type = message_tags[tag][0].type;

                var link = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + message_tag_id + '">' + message_tag_name + '</a>';
                message = message.replace(message_tag_name, link);
              }

            } 

          } 

          entry += '<div class="post-message" style="margin:8px 0;">' + message + '</div>';
        }

        if(post.attachments) {
          var att = post.attachments.data[0];
          if(att.description) var att_description = att.description;
          if(att.type) var att_type = att.type;
          if(att.title) var att_title = att.title;
          switch(att.type) {
            case 'unavailable' :
              entry += '<div class="status-att" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 8px;"><div class="status-att-title" style="font-weight: bold;">' + att_title + '</div><div class="status-att-desc">' + att_description + '</div></div>';
            break;
          }
        }                 

        if(post.to) {
          var to_id = post.to.data[0].id,
              to_name = post.to.data[0].name;
        }

        if(post.updated_time) var updated_time = post.updated_time;

        if(post.likes) {
        }

        if(post.comments) {
        }

      break;

      case 'link' :

        console.log(JSON.stringify(post));



        if(post.attachments) {
          var att = post.attachments.data[0];
          if(att.type) var att_type = att.type + 'd';
          else var att_type = 'posted';
        }

        entry += '<div class="post-title"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + from_id + '">' + from_name + '</a> ' + ((att.type) ? 'shared' : 'posted') + ' a ' + type + ' - <time>' + relativeTime(created_time);

        if(post.application) {
          var app_id = post.application.id,
              app_name = post.application.name,
              app_namespace = post.application.namespace;
          entry += ' via ' + app_name + '</time></div>';
        } else { entry += '</time></div>'; }

        if(post.message) {
          var message = nl2br(post.message);

          if(post.message_tags) {
            var message_tags = post.message_tags;

            for (var tag in message_tags) {

              if (message_tags.hasOwnProperty(tag)) {
                var message_tag_id = message_tags[tag][0].id;
                    message_tag_name = message_tags[tag][0].name;

                var link = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + message_tag_id + '">' + message_tag_name + '</a>';
                message = message.replace(message_tag_name, link);
              }

            } 

          } 

          entry += '<div class="post-message" style="margin:8px 0;">' + message + '</div>';
        }

        if(post.attachments) {
          var att = post.attachments.data[0];
          if(att.subattachments) {
            $(att.subattachments.data).each(function (i, item) {
              var sub_img_height = item.media.image.height,
                  sub_img_width = item.media.image.width,
                  sub_img_src = item.media.image.src,
                  sub_target = item.target.url,
                  sub_type = item.type;

              entry += '<img src="' + sub_img_src + '"/><br/>---<br/>' + target + '<br/>---<br/>' + title + '<br/>---<br/>';

            });
          } else {
            var target = att.target.url,
                title = att.title;
            entry += '<a class="link" href="' + (post.link ? post.link : target) + '" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">';
            if(post.picture) {
              // there's a photo
              if(post.picture.indexOf('imdb') > -1) {
                entry += '<div style="float: left; width: 158px;"><img src="' +  post.picture + '" style="width: 158px;"/></div>';

                entry += '<div style="float: left; width: 400px; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="link-title" style="padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold;">' + title + '</div>';
                if (post.description) entry += '<div class="link-desc" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + post.description +  '</div>';
                if (post.caption) entry += '<div class="link-caption" style="font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #888;">' + post.caption + '</div></div></a>';
                entry += '<div class="clear"></div>';
              } else {
                  // create closure to preserve variables uniquely for each image
                  // and to pass in any outer variables that we need to preserve uniquely for each image
                  (function(imgCntr, description, caption, title) {
                      var placeHolder = "<<img" + imgCntr + ">>";
                      // insert placeholder in the HTML so we can replace it later
                      entry += placeHolder;
                      var picture = post.picture.split('url=');
                      var img = new Image();
                      img.onload = function(){
                        var height = img.height,
                            width = img.width, 
                            html = "";

                        console.log(decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(picture[1])));
                        console.log('Width: ' + width);
                        console.log('Height: ' + height);

                        if(width > height) {
                          // wide photo, above details
                          html += '<img src="' + decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(picture[1])) + '" style="max-width:576px; margin-bottom: 0;" />';

                          html += '<div class="link-details" style="padding: 0 8px 8px 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="link-title" style="padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold;">' + title + '</div>';
                          if (description) html += '<div class="link-desc" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + description +  '</div>';
                          if (caption) html += '<div class="link-caption" style="font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #888;">' + caption + '</div></div></a>';
                          html += '<div class="clear"></div>';
                        } else {
                          // tall photo, left of details
                          html += '<div style="float: left; width: 158px;"><img src="' +  decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(picture[1])) + '" style="max-width: 158px;"/></div>';

                          html += '<div style="float: left; width: 400px; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="link-title" style="padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold;">' + title + '</div>';
                          if (description) html += '<div class="link-desc" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + description +  '</div>';
                          if (caption) html += '<div class="link-caption" style="font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #888;">' + caption + '</div></div></a>';
                          html += '<div class="clear"></div>';
                        }
                        // put this HTML into the right place in the entry string
                        entry = entry.replace(placeHolder, html);
                        --imgCntr;
                        // if all images are done
                        if (imgCntr <= 0) {
                            $('#feed').append(entry);
                        }
                    }
                    img.src = decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(picture[1]));
                  })(imgCntr++, post.description, post.caption, title);

              }

            } else {
              // no picture
              entry += '<div class="link-details" style="width: 558px; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="link-title" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + title + '</div>';
              if (post.description) entry += '<div class="link-desc" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + post.description +  '</div>';
              if (post.caption) entry += '<div class="link-caption" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">' + post.caption + '</div></div></a>';
            }
          }
        } 

      break;
      case 'photo' :
        if(post.message) {
          var message = nl2br(post.message);

          if(post.message_tags) {
            var message_tags = post.message_tags;

            for (var tag in message_tags) {

              if (message_tags.hasOwnProperty(tag)) {
                var message_tag_id = message_tags[tag][0].id;
                    message_tag_name = message_tags[tag][0].name;

                var link = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + message_tag_id + '">' + message_tag_name + '</a>';
                message = message.replace(message_tag_name, link);
              }

            } 

          } 

          entry += '<div class="post-message" style="margin:8px 0;">' + message + '</div>';
        }

        if(post.attachments) {

          var att = post.attachments.data[0];

          if(att.subattachments) {
            var sub = att.subattachments;

          } else {

            switch(att.type) {
              case 'photo' :
                entry += '<a href="' + att.target.url + '" target="_blank"><img class="post-photo" style="max-height: 576px; max-width: 576px; margin: 8px 0;" src="' + att.media.image.src + '"/></a>';

              break;
              case 'unavailable' : 
                var att = post.attachments.data[0];
                entry += '<div class="status-att" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 8px;"><div class="status-att-title" style="font-weight: bold;">' + att.title + '</div><div class="status-att-desc">' + att.description + '</div></div>';
              break;
            }

          }

        }

      break;
      case 'video' :
      break;
    }

    // decrement guard count, since all images have been at least requested now
    --imgCntr;

    // if there was no async part, then entry is done so it can be directly appended
    // if there was an async part, then it will get appended in the async callbacks when the last one of them is done
    if (imgCntr <= 0) {
        $('#feed').append(entry);
    }

  }

});
```

---

FYI, I consider the technique used here a bit of a hack.  It isn't how I would write the code if starting from scratch, but given the volume of code and my inability to test anything I write, rewriting it all in a different way is not practical for me.

Comment: @JustinWhite - in the `case 'link':` branch of your code (which I presume is the part you're asking about), can you describe in words what you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically I get the picture and details for the link. If the picture is landscape (wider than tall) then it goes on top of the details. If the picture is portrait (taller than wide) is goes to the left of the details. It's just like the 'shared link' on Facebook (this is for a Facebook group we're migrating to a website)

Comment: @JustinWhite - OK, I made a stab at hacking a solution into your existing code (added to my answer).  I probably would have written the whole process differently from the start because of the async issue, but without rewriting everything a different way, this is what I can work into what you had.

Comment: Fixed several more issues (more things have be passed into the closure).

Comment: Ok. Console is logging the photo for each iteration separately now, so your solution is doing something. The placeholder however is not being replaced, and something weird is elsewhere in rending of the code. Can you explain exactly what your solution does and how it does it? I'm not very clear on that.

Comment: @JustinWhite - I've written out 6 points about what my code does and why in my answer and have several comments in the code.  Can you please ask a more specific question about what you don't understand?  If the placeHolders are not getting replaced, then do some debugging around this line `entry = entry.replace(placeHolder, html);` with a `console.log(entry)`  and console.log(placeHolder)` to figure out why it's not getting replaced.  Also, note I've made multiple edits in the last 30 mins to fix some things so I don't know which version you grabbed.

Comment: Thanks friend, I'll go through it all and continue to work on it. Thank you for your help!